# Randomly getting 502 bad gateway on browsing healthcheck url https://<domain_name>/healthz

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api

I have created a server in AWS to test GTM server-server tracking. I downloaded the docker image from Google Cloud and run the container using following command:

```
docker container run -d -p 8080:8080 -e CONTAINER_CONFIG=$config_id --name=gtm_tagging_server $image_name
```

And finally I tried to access healthcheck URL `https://<domain_name>/healthz`, but it's returning as 502 bad gateway.

What could cause this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: THe docker container is exposed over port 8080, you are accessing it over port 443. Is there a component in middle which is doing that redirection or proxy

Comment: @VikramS Thank you for identifying this. But internally also we are accessing it in port 8080 only. We already verified that